# MSSQL 2005 Snapshot Agent Uses 100% CPU

Tags: sql-server-2005

When setting up a new subscription to a publication (transactional replication) from 64-bit SQL Server 2005 to 64-bit SQL Server 2005 the Snapshot Agent on the publisher consumes 100% of the CPU. I am using SSMS to create the new subscription. My initial impression is that this could be from row locking occurring during the generation of the snapshot but I have read that a concurrent snapshot is generated by default in SQL Server 2005, and that row locking shouldn't be a concern.

As this is a production server I would like to be able to initialize replication without bringing the box to it's knees. Any suggestions would be helpful and appreciated.

Comment: What process (according to task manager) is spinning the CPU? If the SQL Server then what does it show is going nuts?

Answer (score -1):

is the distribution database running on the production db?
If you want to minimizse the load on your production db, setup the distribution db to run at the subscriber, not the publisher.